# App-wise setting of mobile data selection in dual SIM

Tags: mobile-data, data-monitoring, oneplus-one, dual-sim

In a dual-SIM smartphone, how to set the usage of mobile data to a specific SIM for defined apps?

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. The question was originally tagged with 'oneplus-one'. Did you mean to ask about that device specifically, or more generally?